# How to search a node in treeview control

Tags: c++, visual-c++, treeview

I am trying to search a node in treeview control in c++. There is no method to search a node in c++, it seems.

Please provide your inputs.

Thanks,

-Siva

Comment: I have searched a lot for it.. But found no useful info.

Comment: Did you search here, on StackOverflow?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17774633/how-can-i-find-treeview-node-by-which-label-equals-string-variable